# User snippets at Visual Studio Code stopped to work after newest update

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.20.0

OS Version: Windows 10

Today I have updated VSC to 1.20.0 and suddenly all my html snippets stopped to work.

I have disabled all the extensions but it didn't help.

Here are my settings:

```
{
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
// Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,
// Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
// Enable word based suggestions
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
// Controls whether the editor should render indent guides
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"editor.tabCompletion": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
}
```

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same here on 1.20.1 - nothing seems to get it working again :-(

**UPDATE**
A workaround I've found is to re-create the snippets as **global** snippets (remembering to add the "scope" to each one).

HTH

**UPDATE 2**
I had to restart VSCode to get it to recognize the global snippets - YMMV